# Винительный падеж имен прилагательных во множественном числе

Tags: грамматика

Как объяснить разницу в окончаниях прилагательных во множественном числе в винительном падеже?

Answer (score 2):

Он строит высокие дома → (что?) дома (какие?) высокие В.п мн.ч.-ие- мягкий вариант
Вижу снежинки( какие?) белые легкие. -В.п. -ые-твёрдый вариант.
Вижу высоких ребят.-Вижу (кого?)ребят (каких?) высоких.-одушевлённые сущ. в вин.п. имеют окончания, совпадающие с родит. падежом.

Comment: Спасибо! Исчерпывающий ответ! Лаконично, точно и очень доходчиво.